# Add class to <ul> on sidebar widget

Tags: widgets, sidebar, register-sidebar

I have been looking on stack overflow and the web but can't find a simple solution for this.

I just want to add a class to the  of the widget sidebar generated by Wordpress.

This is my register sidebar code:

```
    register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __(' Main Sidebar ', 'mystic'),
    'id' => 'sidebar-2',
    'class' => 'submenu',
    'description' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'mystic' ),
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => '',
    'before_title' => '<h6>',
    'after_title' => '</h6>'
));
```

The html output of the actual unordered list is:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/a-third-post/">A Third Post</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/another-post/">Another Post</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/news-article-title/">News Article Title</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I want the ul to have a class of 'submenu'

So,

```
<ul class="submenu">
 <li>
  .....
```

Surely there has to be an easy way to do this?(without jQuery)

Comment: The markup of the contents of a widget are determined by the widget, not the sidebar. `register_sidebar()` just lets you add a wrapper around widgets. So whether or not you can do this depends on the specific widget that you're using. What widget are you using here?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, ah. I am using Wordpress's built in "Recent Posts" widget

Comment: In that case, no, there isn't a way. There's no filter for changing the markup of that widget.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I just found this snippet which seems to work. Is it any good? `ob_start();
    dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-2');
    $sidebar = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $sidebar_corrected_ul = str_replace("<ul>", '<ul class="submenu l_tinynav1">', $sidebar);

    echo $sidebar_corrected_ul;`

Comment: Personally? I'd consider it a hack. That code will apply your class to _any_ `<ul>` element in any widget. But if it works, it works.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225867/adding-classes-to-dynamic-sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **functions.php** file :

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_register_sidebars' );
function my_register_sidebars() {
    /* Register the 'primary' sidebar. */
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
            'name'          => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'mystic' ),
            'description'   => __( 'A short description of the sidebar.', 'mystic' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>',
            'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h3>',
        )
    );
    /* Repeat register_sidebar() code for additional sidebars. */
}
```

In **sidebar.php** :

```
<?php
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) ) { ?>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
    </ul>
<?php }
?>
```

**EDIT**
If you are looking to modify the output of Recent Posts Widget,
you can use this [Extend Recent Posts](https://gist.github.com/paulruescher/2998060) Class ;)
All you have to do is to modify it as you want :)

SYA :)

Comment: Thanks, that almost works. But it is added the <ul> above the <h3> and making things look weird

Comment: The `<ul class="submenu">` is now wrapping the sidebar, this is what you asked for. Isn't it ? Remaining modifications are just `CSS`...

Comment: Want it to look like this: `<h6>Latest news</h6><ul class="submenu">
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/a-third-post/">A Third Post</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/another-post/">Another Post</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:8888/news-article-title/">News Article Title</a>
    </li>
</ul>`

Comment: So you only want to target the `ul` of recent posts ?

Comment: yeah, the <h6> and <ul><li> should not sit inside another div or container etc. All I want to do is add a class to the <ul> tag which by default has no class at all it would seem.

Comment: Take a look at the **EDIT** part :) Don't forget to accept the answer when it works for you :)